# Error in dat conversion IOS

Tags: ios, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am using `UIDatePicker` to get the date of birth of a person and display it in the format `January 19, 2012`. I am using the following function to convert the date returned by the date picker to the string format:

```
-(NSString*)stringFromDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSDateFormatter *formater =[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formater setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, YYYY"];

    NSString *str = [formater stringFromDate:date];
    return str;    
}
```

It is working correctly and I am getting the correct date converted to string. Now for calling the web service to save this dat, I am again converting this string into dat using the same date formatter format as shown below:

```
- (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSDateFormatter *formater =[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formater setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, YYYY"];
    NSDate *date = [formater dateFromString:string];
    return date;
}
```

But now, if the date I selected is `October 18, 2006` The above function returns the date as `2005-12-24 18:30:00 +0000`, which is `December 25, 2005` when converted to string using the first function. Even though I am using the same dat formatter, why is this happening in different cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `YYYY` format. Use `yyyy` instead.

So the correct date format looks like `[formater setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];`

That's was your error.